# Five functions to get the digits of a number

Tags: performance, comparative-review, clojure

I'm writing a simple function: given a number, it will return a sequence or a collection of the digits in the number (in the correct order). i.e `(get-digits-fn 1234567) => (1 2 3 4 5 6 7) / [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]`

Below are five attempts at the same function:

```
(defn get-digits-1 [num]
  (->> [num '()]
       (iterate (fn [[num digits]]
                  (when (> num 0)
                    [(quot num 10) (conj digits (rem num 10))])))
       (take-while some?)
       (last)
       (second)))

(defn get-digits-2 [num]
  (when (> num 0)
    (lazy-seq (concat (get-digits-2 (quot num 10)) '((rem num 10))))))

;; Suggested by Carcigenate
(defn get-digits-3 [num]
  (->> (str)
       (map str)
       (map int)
       (into '())))

(defn get-digits-4 [num]
  (loop [n num
         res '()]
    (if (= n 0)
      res
      (recur (quot n 10) (conj res (rem n 10))))))

(defn get-digits-5 [num]
  (->>
   (iterate (fn [[n digits]]
              [(quot n 10) (conj digits (rem n 10))])
            [num '()])
   (drop-while #(not= 0 (first %)))
   (first)
   (second)))
```

A helper function for testing performance:

```
(defn quick-bench-get-digits [fn range]
  (quick-bench (->> range
                    (map fn)
                    (map (partial apply vector))
                    (into []))))
```

The perf results (output truncated to only show execution time mean):

```
eul> (quick-bench-get-digits get-digits-1 (range 1 100000))
Execution time mean : 129.516521 ms

eul> (quick-bench-get-digits get-digits-2 (range 1 100000))
Execution time mean : 128.637055 ms

eul> (quick-bench-get-digits get-digits-3 (range 1 100000))
Execution time mean : 24.267716 ms

eul> (quick-bench-get-digits get-digits-4 (range 1 100000))
Execution time mean : 25.083393 ms

eul> (quick-bench-get-digits get-digits-5 (range 1 100000))
Execution time mean : 145.430443 ms
```

It looks like `get-digits-3` is the fastest while `get-digits-4` is closely behind. (As the numbers increase, `get-digits-3` outperforms `get-digits-4`. i.e try `(range 1000000 2000000)`)

1. Any way to increase performance more without leaving Clojure land?
2. If mutability and Java inter-op is allowed, is there a way to increase performance?

p.s. functions 1 and 5 are almost identical. This was incremental exploration.

Comment: Is performance of this code specifically really a concern? I'm doubtful that this is what would be the choking point of the program. 24ms is very fast, especially for an inflated test case.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid your code has errors,  so your benchmarking is invalid.

- The `get-digits-3` function is wrong.
- A corrected version runs about twelve times slower than
  `get-digits-4`.

**Repairing `get-digits-3`**

Your `get-digits-3` doesn't work:

```
=> (get-digits-3 123456789)
()
```

The function chain should be applied to the argument `num`:

```
(defn get-digits-3 [num]
  (->> num
       (str)
       (map str)
       (map int)
       (into '())))
```

But this fails:

```
=> (get-digits-3 123456789)
ClassCastException java.base/java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.base/java.lang.Character  clojure.lang.RT.intCast (RT.java:1213)
```

The culprit is the `(map int)` line. You can't apply `int` to strings. If you drop the offending line, you get the character values:

```
=> (get-digits-3 123456789)
(57 56 55 54 53 52 51 50 49)
```

Notice, too, that they are in reverse order. So we

- subtract the value of character `0` and
- `conj` onto the other end by using a vector.

This gives us ...

```
(defn get-digits-3 [num]
  (->> num
       (str)
       (map int)
       (map #(- % (int \0)))
       (into [])))

=> (get-digits-3 123456789)
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

**Benchmarking**

I went about this differently:

- I used a single example instead of a range.
- I used Criterium's `bench` rather than its `quick-bench`.

The results were as follow:

For your original (faulty) version of `get-digits-3`:

```
=> (bench (get-digits-3 123456789))
...
             Execution time mean : 228.998292 ns
```

For the corrected version:

```
=> (bench (get-digits-3 123456789))
...
             Execution time mean : 3.440024 µs
```

And for `get-digits-4`:

```
=>(bench (get-digits-4 123456789))
...
             Execution time mean : 247.502418 ns
```

This confirms that your faulty `get-digits-3` is about as fast as `get-digits-4`. And `get-digits-3` ignores its argument, so is bound to get relatively faster as the numbers get bigger. You can see that the corrected version is nowhere near competitive.